# rpm command hangs when executed as non-root user on RHEL7

Tags: rpm, rhel7

I have a weird problem where the rpm command hangs for 40 seconds (it's always exactly 40 seconds) when executed as any non-root user. It doesn't matter what command line arguments are used, even "rpm" without any arguments hangs (rpm --help is the only exception).

strace shows that it hangs on a select() call with two file descriptors pointing to /etc/passwd and /etc/pam.d/other, which doesn't make any sense to me.

When executed as root it completes immediately.

The system is RHEL 7, I observed the issue on two completely different machines in different customer environments.

I'm looking for a solution or some hints where to continue the investigation.

Comment: DNS resolution problem. Or maybe your system is integrated with LDAP/AD which is inaccessible.

Comment: Is there any log that would give more details on this? None of the two boxes should be using LDAP or AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the issue was caused by incorrect permissions on /etc/hosts. Changing them to 644 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a DNS resolution problem. Hard to say what is the precise cause and there is no general log relating to DNS queries and their errors/results.

- Check /etc/nsswitch.conf
- Check /etc/resolv.conf
- Check some `host` queries to point you in the right direction:

  host localhost

  host localhost.localdomain

  hostname

  host $(hostname)

  hostname -s

  host $(hostname -s)

  hostname -f

  host $(hostname -f)

Comment: I don't have access to the machine right now, so I didn't try your suggestions yet, but I doubt it's DNS. If any DNS requests were made the operation of opening an UDP socket to port 53 would be visible in the strace output - but it isn't.